# Is dwelling on bad thoughts towards Islam a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, evil-thoughts

There is nothing mentioning that if a person thinks badly about Islam, then he is doing sin. In Islam speaking or acting on it is sin.

Is dwelling on bad thoughts towards Islam a sin?